# How to batch convert a directory of images to thumbnails?

Tags: export, image, files-and-directories

I have 50k images to resize, my first attempt at this was:

```
fromDir = "~/Downloads/full/"; (*this is where the images are*)
thumbDir = "~/Downloads/thumbs/"; (*empty*)
files = FileNames["*", dir];

ParallelDo[Export[thumbDir <> FileNameTake[i], 
   Thumbnail[Import[i], 100]], {i, files}]
```

But it takes too long a time. Is there any way to speed this process up?

Comment: [ParallelDo](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelDo.html)?

Comment: Ooops! Yes that was what I tried, I wrote the wrong one. Wondering if there is some specialized way to do this.

Comment: I think, there are ways to operate on an image without actually importing it, I'll need to double-check the documentation. But besides that, a small bash script and a console based image manipulation utility running under ubuntu once did the trick much faster for me. It was also around 50k images, I forget the name though.

Comment: It seems, `ImageFile xxx` functions will not be applicable to you in this case, as they are only suitable for working on pixels, not images as a whole. If keeping to the scope of Mathematica, I can suggest low-level file operations, but this will be a tough manual labor path. Alternatively, use tools better suited for the job. If I find the utility I used, I'll link it here.

Comment: Sorry for being off-topic, but here's the solution that helped me
http://askubuntu.com/questions/135477/how-can-i-scale-all-images-in-a-folder-to-the-same-width

Comment: @LLlAMnYP yes it seems that out of core methods don't apply here, I'm thinking of the image magic cli.

Comment: http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/04/29/gigapixel-images-in-mathematica/ This blog post seems relevant. I'm thinking, a clever use of the methods laid out there and, perhaps, reading up on the related "multigig TIF stacks" question can be a good starting point.

Comment: Seems like the LargerImage function is similar to the new DynamicImage function in 10.4 - I'd like to see how it handles a gigapixel image!

Answer (score 7):

Well, regardless, whether MMA is the best tool for the job or not, we can always have it our way.

As always, `Trace[..., TraceInternal -> True]` and

```
<<GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitions[...]
```

are our friend. I was truly shocked, at just how much needless evaluation is going on under the cover of Import. So I spelunked my way down to the core functions, implemented **not** in the Wolfram language. And I reckon, there's hardly a faster way to do, what's being done in the procedural loop, than like so:

```
Image`ImportExportDump`ImageWritePNG[
  "test2.png", 
  ImageResize[
    First@
      Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG["test.png"], 
    300]] // AbsoluteTiming // First

(* 0.0257 *)
```

Of course, this is a rather small png image that I used as a test. Sadly, the improvement over normal `Import` and `Export`, even without specifying options and such is only threefold. At a filesize of 1.6 MB the margin closes to 0.5 seconds vs 0.6 seconds. Image processing is *slow* in MMA!

Answer (score 4):

For amusement, here is an `ImageFile` approach..

```
(wid = First@Import["lena.tiff", "ImageSize"];
  i = 0;
  n = 5;
  i0 = Image[Partition[Reap[ImageFileScan[(
          If[Mod[i, n] == 0 && Mod[j, n] == 0, Sow[#]];
          i = i + 1;
          If[i == wid, i = 0, j = j + 1]) &, 
        "lena.tiff"]][[2, 1]],
     Ceiling[wid/n]]]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

This is *way* slower than `ThumbNail[Import[..]]` .. maybe useful if you have  a huge image on a memory limited machine..

Actually, just running

```
ImageFileScan[Null &, "file.tiff"]
```

is about 10x slower than `Import`

Comment: I don't think Null& is really a good measure, I'd try #&, and maybe compare to Import+Export

Comment: The partitioning is hilarious, though, everything you should never do in MMA, +1